# How do I apply different styles according to content type?

Tags: search

in a view I'm filtering  content with search API /facets. In the view (field format) i've applied a specific style for the results, some sort of Bootstrap card. IT apply to all content index by search API.

I need to apply different styles according to content type in the results: For the content type "rose" i use a bootstrap card, for the content type "wood" i use full width div with an image a button and a text.

How can i achieve that?

I tried to duplicate the view with the same path parameter (/search), and tried  relation/contextual filter but it s not working. And as the view overwrite the display style of the search API "rendered_item", i cant use those, maybe i should?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in the search API view,  i had to change the "format display" from field to rendered entity, and in the parameter i choose a display format for the different content type. then i will customize if trough twig template, instead in the view with custom text as like that it apply to any content type.